# Directional/Non-Directional Risk

Tags: risk, finance

Can someone explain to me what is direction/non-directional risk?
Went through few sites but couldn't understand much.

Comment: Please, would you provide a link or some other reference. "Directional risk" can mean a lot. Is it the contect of options? Which asset class?

Comment: this is in the case of FRM.  Below is as link to some definition:    http://www.flashcardmachine.com/frm-schweser-topic1.html

Answer (score 1):

These terms mean different things in different circles.

Options traders would consider any exposure to price changes in the underlying to be a directional risk. A hedged option position  still has non-directional risk though, since option prices can change without any change in the price of the underlying. Equities traders would generally not consider exposure to a price change in a stock as necessarily constituting directional risk. They are more likely to only consider exposure to price changes in the broad market or sector as a directional risk. Macro traders generally only consider exposure to changes in major aggregates (e.g. crude oil prices, the dollar) to constitute directional risk.